# How to solve this minimal js code issue?

Tags: javascript

My inputs are: an array of object names and objects. I want to loop through the array for object name and then output something from corresponding object. My code is as follows:

```
    options=["bold","italic"] ;

    var bold ={
            action: function(){
                alert("<strong>just bold</strong>");
            },
            b_p: "-40px bold"
     };

    var italic ={
            action: function(){
                alert("<em>an italic</em>");
            },
            b_p: "-20px italic"
     };

     for(i=0;i<options.length;++i)
     {
         document.write(options[i].b_p);
     }
```

My desired output: "-40px bold -20px italic" but I get an error saying: "undefined undefined".

Please help me to find out my mistake/ignorance here.

Thanks.

/**************/
Update: the problem is solved below :-) Thanks communtiy

Comment: Write out the steps your code is going through on paper and you'll find the problem.

Comment: well, options is just an array of strings, and a string does not have a "b_p" property. Or I'm misunderstanding something in your exemple.

Comment: @john yah! you got it right. I just guessed this solution from php, wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the names, pass an object array:

```
var bold = {
            action: function(){
                alert("<strong>just bold</strong>");
            },
            b_p: "-40px bold"
};

var italic = {
            action: function(){
                alert("<em>an italic</em>");
            },
            b_p: "-20px italic"
};

var options = [ bold, italic ]; // symbols, not strings

for(var i=0;i<options.length;++i)
{
         document.write(options[i].b_p);
}
```

Nothing else would really need to change.

Comment: Needs to come after the variables are defined.

Comment: Actually options would need to be declared after bold and italic in this case

Comment: Hey "tvanfossen" :-D your suggestion made it correct.......so basically when options=[bold,italic] line is executed both bold and italic are considered as null since no such variable is declared before that.

Comment: @zzz - if you want me to see a comment, you need to prefix my name with the `@` symbol as I've done with yours.  Only the first three characters are needed.  FWIW, no 'e' in my name.

Comment: This might be a misunderstanding on my part, but wouldn't hoisting allow for `options` to be declared before `bold` and `italic`, as long as `bold` and `italic` are declared with `var`?

Comment: Ah, scratch that.  The variable names would be declared but their contents would still be undefined.

Comment: I alt tab back and my answer has exploded in comments!

Answer (score 2):

A few problems here:

`options=["bold","italic"] ;` 
should be `options=[bold,italic];`

and should be *after* the declaration of the `bold` and `italic` vars

Also, `for(i=0;i<options.length;++i)` should be `for(i=0;i<options.length;i++)` (note the post-increment instead of a pre-increment)

So to sum it up:

```
var bold ={
        action: function(){
            alert("<strong>just bold</strong>");
        },
        b_p: "-40px bold"
 };

var italic ={
        action: function(){
            alert("<em>an italic</em>");
        },
        b_p: "-20px italic"
 };

 var options=[bold,italic];

 for(i=0;i<options.length;i++)
 {
     document.write(options[i].b_p);
 }
```

Comment: @Damp hey, you summed up nice :-) please tell me why you preferred post-increment more? any special reason? In this case, both are identical, isn't it?

Comment: @zzz_corp Actually you're right, It doesn't matter that much... I'm just used to seeing it that way

Comment: @zzz - either are acceptable. Pre-increment is marginally more efficient (if the implementation is stupid) since it won't need to keep the original value around. In pratice this idiom is probably handled the same way for both. Search for just about any question on the issue of pre-/post-increment on SO for more info.

Comment: @zzz - it really should declare i as local to the scope, though, using `var`.  `for (var i=0; i<options.length;++i) { }`

Comment: @tva As "i" is considered loop index throughout of my code so i just skipped this variable scope.

Comment: @zzz - that's just the problem.  If you don't declare it there, then it's in the global scope.  What happens if you call a function inside your loop that also has a loop that uses i as a counter (without declaring it local).  You ought to get in the habit of making variables locally scoped by default to avoid these kinds of insidious problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much more cleaner approach:

```
var options = {
    "bold": {
        "action": "<strong>just bold</strong>",
        "b_p": "-40px bold"
    },

    "italic": {
        "action": "<em>an italic</em>",
        "b_p": "-20px italic"
    }
};

for (var i in options) {
    document.write(options[i]["b_p"] + "<br />")
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sea2d/

If you wanted to alert your action, you could just use:

```
alert(options["bold"]["action"]);
```

Comment: yeh, this is a nice approach but my requirement is to use both array and object concepts.